# Codeigniter call from one function in to the other function

Tags: codeigniter

I have a simple question. But, can't solve at this moment in my Codeigniter Project. I want to get an amount from one function into other function. I used the following code :

### Destination function

```
public function deletePayment($id)
    {
       $this->Fees->approveImprest($id)->amount;
    }
```

### Source Function

```
public function approveImprest($id)
        {
          ......
          ......
        }
```

But the code outs following Notice :
A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Fees::$Fees

Filename: controllers/Fees.php

Line Number: 1845
```

What is going-on. Can anyone help ? "Fees" is the name of Controller. These two functions are in the same controller "Fees".

Comment: Is Both the function on a same Controller ? If Yes  You can use $this->deletePayment($id)

Comment: If they're in the same controller, try `$this->approveImprest($id)->amount;`

Comment: @ Marleen. If I try this, whole line was underlined.

Comment: @ Punit Gajjar. No. I want to get amount which is in the function  "approveImprest"

Comment: What does the contents of the `approveImprest($id)` function look like? If you want to call `->amount` on its return value, it should return an object.

Comment: @ Marleen. The function, approveImprest($id) has included some values. "amount" is also there.

Comment: You may simply need to use `$this->approveImprest($id);` instead, as you don't seem to be doing anything with the `->amount` value in `deletePayment`. But it's hard to tell without seeing what `approveImprest` looks like.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot call a controller method from another controller directly

my first solution is to use ["Creating Core System Classes"](http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html) to make a core controller

make a class on [application/core](http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html) directory:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       // Your own constructor code
    }
 public function index() {
      // some codes here
    }

 public function approveImprest($id){
      // some codes here
    }
}
```

extend your controller from core

```
class Main extends MY_Controller {

 public function index() {
     // some codes here
 }

 public function deletePayment($id){
     $this->approveImprest($id)->amount;
 }
}
```

Other solutions:

2 - [Use Model](http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html)

3 - [Creating Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html)